# Avoid code repeating c#

Tags: c#, repeat

Currently making library for multimeter and I'm at this point where I find that I'm repeating myself. I'm asking, how to connect those two functions. This is just the beginning, I'm going to have similar functions a lot more, all I need is some kind of example, or fix for this particular code, then I am able to figure others out myself.

```
public string MeasureVoltage()
{
    string Meas = "MEAS:VOLT:";
    if (vt == VoltageType.DC)
    {
       Meas += "DC?";
    }
    else
    {
       Meas += "AC?";
    }
    io.PrintfAndFlush(Meas + "\n");
    Console.WriteLine(Meas);
    string response;
    io.Scanf("%s", out response);
    return response;
}

public string MeasureCurrent()
{
    string Meas = "MEAS:CURR:";
    if (ct == CurrentType.DC)
    {
       Meas += "DC?";
    }
    else
    {
       Meas += "AC?";
    }
    io.PrintfAndFlush(Meas + "\n");
    Console.WriteLine(Meas);
    string response;
    io.Scanf("%s", out response);
    return response;
}

public enum VoltageType { AC, DC }
public enum CurrentType { AC, DC }
```

Comment: If this code works correctly it probably belongs on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) instead

Comment: Try Read something about SOLID, DRY, KISS, and try to get the abstraction or the least common denominator every time you start duplicating, then extract the method, class, etc..

Comment: `io.Scanf`? Seems not like C# to me. Aprt from this you should determine what is equal between the two methods and extract that into a metod, and only have the two remaining on ifferent parts. All I can see is the different value for `Meas`, making this a perfect candidate for an inout-param into your method and copy all the rest into a new method.

Comment: Funny enum: voltage type = ... current

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public string MeasureVoltage()
{
    return DoMeasurement($"MEAS:VOLT:{vt.ToString()}?");
}

public string MeasureCurrent()
{
    return DoMeasurement($"MEAS:CURR:{ct.ToString()}?");
}

private string DoMeasurement(string Meas)
{
    io.PrintfAndFlush(Meas + "\n");
    Console.WriteLine(Meas);
    string response;
    io.Scanf("%s", out response);
    return response;
}

public enum VoltageType { AC, DC }
public enum CurrentType { AC, DC }
```

Pretty easy, huh? :)

The `$""` syntax is what's called [*interpolated string*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings) and it's available in C# 6.0. If you're working out an earlier version, you can replace it with  `string.Format()`, like so:

```
DoMeasurement(stringFormat("MEAS:VOLT:{0}?", vt.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the best I can do with the code you provided:

```
public enum VoltageType { AC, DC}
public enum CurrentType { AC, DC}

public string MeasureVoltage()
{
    return Measure(MeasureType.Voltage);
}
public string MeasureCurrent()
{
    return Measure(MeasureType.Current);
}

private enum MeasureType {Voltage, Current}

private string Measure(MeasureType mt)
{
    var what = (mt == Voltage) ? "VOLT" : "CURR";
    var type = ((mt == MeasureType.Voltage && vt == VoltageType.AC) || 
                (mt == MeasureType.Current && ct == CurrentType.AC)) ? "AC" : "DC";

    // c# 6 or higher:
    var Meas = $"MEAS:{what}:{type}?";
    // for older versions of c#, use string.Format:
    // var Meas = string.Format("MEAS:{0}:{1}?", what, type);
    io.PrintfAndFlush(Meas + "\n");
    Console.WriteLine(Meas);
    string response;
    io.Scanf("%s", out response);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Worth adding that String interpolation is C# 6 and may not work for him.

Comment: I'd get rid of `VoltageType` enum. Even when measuring Voltage, it's still the Current type that would be Alternating *Current* or Direct *Current*. All Multimeters I have seen have only one switch for AC/DC.

Comment: @Fildor The `VoltageType` and `CurrentType` enums were in the original code, they just weren't defined.

Comment: @Jaquez I know. Just saying.

Comment: @Fildor I agree, but that's in the original code, as Jaquez wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the first lines with this:

```
public string MeasureVoltage()
{
     string Meas = "MEAS:VOLT:" + (vt == VoltageType.DC ? "DC?" : "AC?");
     return Measure(meas);
}

public string MeasureCurrent()
{
    string Meas = "MEAS:CURR:" + (ct == CurrentType.DC ? "DC?" : "AC?");
    return Measure(meas);
}
```

Now extract what is common between both methods into this:

```
private string Measure(string measure)
{
    io.PrintfAndFlush(Meas + "\n");
    Console.WriteLine(Meas);
    string response;
    io.Scanf("%s", out response);
    return response;
}
```

A far better approach would be to have two independent values, one that stores the type of measure (`volt` or `current`) and one for the type of what ever it is (`DC` or `AC`):

```
class MyType
{
    private string Type; // either CURR or VOLT
    private string otherType;  // either DC or AC

    public MyType(string type, otherType)
    { /* fill the members */ }
}
```

Now you don´t even need two methods, just this:

```
public string Measure()
{
    var measure = "MEAS:" + this.Type + ":" + this.OtherType + "?\n";
    io.PrintfAndFlush(measure );
    Console.WriteLine(measure );
    string response;
    io.Scanf("%s", out response);
    return response;
}
```

Now simply call this:

```
var m = new MyType("VOLT", "AC");
var result = m.Measure();
```

which will print `"MEAS:VOLT:AC?"`.

Answer (score 1):

The first question you should ask yourself in these situations is "is it really the same?".

If it is, then you're right, it's probably a duplication and probably should be avoided. Note I've said "probably" - this isn't a hard rule, sometimes duplication can be necessary, or even good, e.g. if it adds to clarity.

If it isn't, then avoiding seemingly duplicated code can actually be a bad thing. Not only can it make your code more confusing but it can miss the point entirely - e.g. if you had a dog object and a table object and decided that because they both have 4 legs they're the same thing you could be faced with people trying to put their coffee on Spot - and I'm fairly sure he'd object! Note a few calls to the same methods, especially if they're utility methods like `WriteLine` don't count as duplication.

In your case I think you've got 2 aspects to the behaviour - determining which measurement to take and then taking the measurement.

Looking at your code your "taking the measurement" stuff is identical; a good first step might be to pull it out into a "Measure" method like this

```
public string MeasureVoltage()
{
    string Meas = "MEAS:VOLT:";
    if (vt == VoltageType.DC)
    {
       Meas += "DC?";
    }
    else
    {
       Meas += "AC?";
    }
    return Measure(Meas);
}

public string MeasureCurrent()
{
    string Meas = "MEAS:CURR:";
    if (ct == CurrentType.DC)
    {
       Meas += "DC?";
    }
    else
    {
       Meas += "AC?";
    }
    return Measure(Meas);
}

public string Measure(string Meas)
{
    io.PrintfAndFlush(Meas + "\n");
    Console.WriteLine(Meas);
    string response;
    io.Scanf("%s", out response);
    return response;
}
```

Note I've kept your code formatting to illustrate that it's a simple "copy everything in `Measure` into a separate method and replace it with a call to `Measure(Meas)`.

Taking this a step further; your Voltage and Current enums are identical - there is little point in this from a code point of view and, anyway, it's not like you get AC voltage with DC current. Taking this into account you can remove the duplication - lets call the replacement "PowerType" given it covers both. Furthermore, you could decide that this power type and the measurement type were both parameters of your measure method and do something like this

```
public enum PowerType { AC, DC }

public string Measure(string measurementType, PowerType pt)
{
    string powerString = pt == PowerType.AC ? "AC" : "DC";
    string measurement = measurementType + powerString;

    io.PrintfAndFlush(measurement + "\n");
    Console.WriteLine(measurement);
    string response;
    io.Scanf("%s", out response);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Nice catch on `PowerType`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd put

```
io.PrintfAndFlush(Meas + "\n");
Console.WriteLine(Meas);
string response;
io.Scanf("%s", out response);
return response;
```

in its own method and call that from both:

```
public string MeasureVoltage()
{
    string Meas = "MEAS:VOLT:";
    if (vt == VoltageType.DC)
    {
        Meas += "DC?";
    }
    else
    {
        Meas += "AC?";
    }
    return PerformMeasurement(Meas);
}

public string MeasureCurrent()
{
    string Meas = "MEAS:CURR:";
    if (ct == CurrentType.DC)
    {
        Meas += "DC?";
    }
    else
    {
        Meas += "AC?";
    }
    return PerformMeasurement(Meas);
}

private string PerformMeasurement(string Meas)
{
    io.PrintfAndFlush(Meas + "\n");
    Console.WriteLine(Meas);
    string response;
    io.Scanf("%s", out response);
    return response;
}
```

If you want `MeasureVoltage`/`MeasureCurrent` to appear shorter, inline the creation of `Meas`:

```
public string MeasureVoltage() => PerformMeasurement( $"MEAS:VOLT:{vt}?" );
```

edit: you can drop the `if` completely, if you can chose the `enum` value names to match the required strings.

Comment: @Downvoter: care to explain what exactly is wrong here?

Comment: IMHO still too much duplication

Comment: One line? (`public string MeasureVoltage() => PerformMeasurement( $"MEAS:VOLT:{vt}?" );`) If you want to keep two different methods, it won't get any shorter.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you could make a Measure method, and give a parameter of what you want it to measure, and just use a switch statement for the stuff that is different between your current methods

Comment: Doesn't that violate the open close principle?

Comment: Good point, I was thinking of something like Zohar Peled's solution.